# python pandas read text file, skip particular lines

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a text file using `pd.read_csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delimiter = "\t")
```

My text file (see below) has a few lines of text before the dataset I need to import begins. **How do I skip the lines before the dataset headers?** I don't want to use any solution that involves counting the number of lines I need to skip because I have to do this for multiple (similar, not same) text files. Any help is appreciated!

Note: I cannot upload the text file as it is confidential

```
========================================= 
hello 123
========================================= 
Dir: /x/y/z/RTchoice/release001/data 
Date: 17-Mar-2020 10:0:08 
Output File: /a/b/c/filename.txt 
N: 2842
-----------------------------------------
Subject col1    col2    col3    
001 10.00000    1.00000 3.00000 
002 11.00000    2.00000 4.00000
```

Comment: use the `skiprows` argmument. `pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delimeter='\t', skiprows=8)`

Comment: I don't want to use any solution that involves counting the number of lines I need to skip because I have to do this for multiple (similar, not same) text files. Do you think there is a way I can count the number of rows I need to skip without opening up the text files maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Then you have to identify the line somehow.  Is it the `'---------'` that breaks the header from the data?  You tell me.  You can't just craft magic.  There has to be some logic to it.

Comment: yeah I get that. I was just wondering if there is a more efficient way but maybe not. So I guess I could just index for the last '---------' and use that index in the `skiprows` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt to 'craft  magic'. The idea is to try `read_csv` with different `skiprows` until it works

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO(
'''
========================================= 
hello 123
========================================= 
Dir: /x/y/z/RTchoice/release001/data 
Date: 17-Mar-2020 10:0:08 
Output File: /a/b/c/filename.txt 
N: 2842
-----------------------------------------
Subject col1    col2    col3    
001 10.00000    1.00000 3.00000 
002 11.00000    2.00000 4.00000
''')

for n in range(1000):
    try:
        data.seek(0)
        df = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter = "\s+", skiprows=n)
    except:
        print(f'skiprows = {n} failed (exception)')   
    else:
        if len(df.columns) == 1: # do not let it get away with a single-column df
            print(f'skiprows = {n} failed (single column)')
        else:   
            break
print('\n', df)
```

output:

```
skiprows = 0 failed (exception)
skiprows = 1 failed (exception)
skiprows = 2 failed (exception)
skiprows = 3 failed (exception)
skiprows = 4 failed (exception)
skiprows = 5 failed (exception)
skiprows = 6 failed (exception)
skiprows = 7 failed (exception)
skiprows = 8 failed (single column)

    Subject  col1  col2  col3
0        1  10.0   1.0   3.0
1        2  11.0   2.0   4.0
```

Comment: this is dark magic, I agree.. but was inspired by your comment!

Comment: I got the reference (-:

Comment: see if it works in 'real life' for you! I myself would describe this as more 'hacky' than 'beautiful' but thanks :-)

Comment: yup, it worked! I had never encountered try/except/else before so this was also a good learning opportunity :]